# C#: dynamically check if the finalizer thread is blocked

Tags: c#, multithreading, garbage-collection, finalizer

I want to check if one finalizer method caused the finalizer thread to hang forever: is the finalizer thread in a blocked state (like a deadlock) or not.

If there are variations in different CLRs, I'm focused on standard .NET framework for Windows in versions higher than (say) 4.5.

I wrote the following code testing if a dummy object gets finalized. I assume:

- there is only one finalizer thread (is it correct ?)
- all finalizers run on the finalizer thread (is it correct ?)

Dummy object:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Little class to test if the finalizer thread is alive. 
    /// Just runs an action when finalized
    /// </summary>
    private class DummyObject
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Action to run when finalized
        /// </summary>
        private Action Finalized;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public DummyObject(Action finalized)
        {
            Finalized = finalized;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Finalizer
        /// </summary>
        ~DummyObject()
        {
            Finalized();
        }
    }
```

Main code:

```
            bool finalized = false;
            var obj = new DummyObject(() => finalized = true);
            obj = null;
            GC.Collect();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.Write("Finalizer thread is alive: " + finalized);
```

The exact question is:
**If this code displays true, does this prove the finalizer thread is not blocked?**

Comment: I assume you're asking in the context of the windows desktop CLR specifically  and not any other runtime? Because for C# "The garbage collector is allowed wide latitude in deciding when to collect objects and run destructors. Specifically, the timing of destructor invocations is not deterministic, and destructors may be executed on any thread. " (quote from C# spec)

Comment: [Link to C# 6 spec containing above quote](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/introduction#destructors)

Comment: My question is general. But I'm focused on a windows service running on a server and using server GC. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Yes, but the point is, the answer is going to be CLR specific. Some implementations of .NET these days (think the Xamarin IOS one is one example) uses reference counting and deterministic GC, and I haven't delved into the details but wouldn't be surprised if the current thread is hijacked for running finalizers at appropriate points.

Comment: I see. Yes I was talking of standard .NET for Windows written by Bill Gates himself. I added it to the question.

Comment: "written by Bill Gates himself"????????????

Comment: In principle, the runtime optimizer could eliminate this temporary object, replacing the code by the finalizer action (assigning `true` to the variable) or even be more radical, eliminating the local variable as well, changing the entire code to `Console.Write("Finalizer thread is alive: true");` (letting aside `GC.Collect(); Thread.Sleep(1000);` which still may have the effect of slowing down the execution). Of course, this result doesn’t say anything about the chance of objects truly needing a finalizer thread, to make progress. All you’ve proved, is that *one object* made progress.

Comment: In theory maybe. In practice the runtime optimize does not go 10% that far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really, really need such a self-diagnostic, I would rather not rely on such implementation details (although now - quite correct). I would rather write logic of self-checking `FinalizersStart` and `FinalizersStop` ETW/LLTng events being emitted. You can do it easily with [the help of the TraceEvent library](https://github.com/Microsoft/perfview/blob/master/documentation/TraceEvent/TraceEventProgrammersGuide.md).